# How to get referenced fields of a particular node/content type?

Tags: 8, paragraphs

I have a content type with reference field of type [paragraph](https://www.drupal.org/project/paragraphs).

Using below code only gives me fields of content type and does not give referenced fields. How can I get referenced fields of a particular node type?

```
function hook_form_alter(array &$form, FormStateInterface &$form_state, $form_id) {
    $entityManager = \Drupal::service('entity.manager');
    $fields = $entityManager->getFieldDefinitions('node','media');
}
```

Comment: if you want to fill referenced paragraph fields with data on a new node before the form is displayed you might consider using a node controller https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/236871/pre-fill-multiple-paragraphs-while-adding-node

Answer (score 0):

Once you have a `$node` object, you can get the referenced field value by the following code:

```
$node->get('field_reference')->referencedEntities();
```

Here, `field_reference` is a field of type `Entity reference revisions` referencing to the paragraph entity.

Comment: How to get $node object?

Comment: @SugandhKhanna Depends on where you write this code. Can you add more details to the question stating where (function?) you need the referenced entities.

Comment: edited, need referenced nodes in hook_form_alter and need to alter referenced nodes to be required=True.

Comment: And I can't load the node for this, because I need to alter referenced fields at the time of adding a node not at edit.